# How to say "Next time" in the past tense?

Tags: grammar

I'm a bit confused on how to use the expression "The next time" in chinese.
I originally wrote
(after going to Kigali for the first he realized there were no ethiopian restaurants) 
于是， 他下次回基加利时， 就决定开这个餐厅。
But my friend told me that  a better way of saying it is 
他再次回基加利时

Answer (score 3):

`下次` : `next time`

`再次` : `once again`

You said it's in the past tense, I think `再次` is better.

`于是，当他再次回到基加利时，就决定开这个餐厅。`

Answer (score 2):

'下次' means in the future. '再次' is better here.

Answer (score 1):

Both 下次 and 再次 suggest that he returned to Kigali more than once. If that's not what you mean, use neither: 他回到基加利後， 就决定开这家餐厅

Note that you use 家 with shops, not 个